# CSS default div positioning

Tags: html, css

Here is something I dont understand.
First of all my code and jsfiddle:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="appWrapper">
  <div id="app_logo">

  </div>
  <div id="app_text1">

  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
div#appWrapper {
    padding: 1em;
    width: 80%;
    height: 85%;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: white;
}

div#app_logo {
    margin: 1em;
    height: 20em;
    width: 20em;
    background-color: #FFD300;
}

div#app_text1 {
    margin: 1em;
    height: 20em;
    width: 25em;
    background-color: #7109AA;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/JfMb2/embedded/result/

**Question:**

Why is the element app_text1 positioned under the app_logo element and not right of it?

What do I have to change so that it is positioned right of it?

Comment: Include both divs in a single span?  I thought this was useful...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4153422/difference-between-div-and-span-tag

Comment: Div's are block level elements, if you want wrapping behavior, you need to add "float:left" to at least the app_logo style.  That or use explicit positioning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why is the element app_text1 positioned under the app_logo element and
>   not right of it?

Because by default, div elements are block level and take up the full width of their parent.

> What do I have to change so that it is positioned right of it?

Float it left.

```
div#app_logo {
    margin: 1em;
    height: 20em;
    width: 20em;
    background-color: #FFD300;
    float:left;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/JfMb2/1/)**

Comment: Kudos for providing a jsFiddle with your response!

Answer (score 2):

There are different kinds of displays: `inline` and `block`. Block elements are always displayed one under another by default, while inline elements are displayed together in line (doh).

**Inline:**

Css code:

```
display: inline;
```

Default for `<span>` and `<a>`

**Block**

Css code:

```
display: block;
```

Default for many more html tags, e.g `<div>`, `<img>`, `<li>`, `<h1>`, `<p>`

Comment: Setting the display to inline will cause various block-level properties to be ignored, but yes, you could make a div act like a span by changing the display value.

Comment: Yeah I think I focused too much on the first question. Using `float` attribute, or perhaps changing the second div to a span, is a much better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Like others already said. Div are block elements, who by default, will have a width of 100% of their parent. Inline element, will display inline and will adjust width with content. In your case, inline-block should be perfect, a mix from inline and block. Acting like a div for styling and aligning horizontally like you want. Inline-block element will not break the floating of your page so no need of `clear:both` under them.

See your [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JfMb2/2/) up to date using `display:inline-block;`